# Dedicate Magento ADMIN virtual machine and Percona Cluster

Tags: magento-enterprise, database

i want to add to my current infrastructure a dedicated virtual machine only for /admin. In the same time, i'm adding a node to my percona single database, to create a master/master configuration.

My question is: can i configure that this vm with /admin would write on second node so that the load can be splitted?

thanks

Comment: Your admin server will be easy, just choose a new URL, but I am confused about your cluster comment. A cluster will give you a single point to write/read to. You shouldn't have to do anything on the Magento side. (Someone can correct me if I am wrong!)

Comment: What i mean is in a mysql clutered master/master i can eventually write on any node and still keep cluster synced across all nodes so that o can use a separate vm for /admim and also a dedicated mysql server that in the same time is part of a cluster always in sync. Sounds good to me :)

Comment: Just one more comment, we were able to fulfill more the 25,000 orders in 12 hours on a single MySQL server and 20 Web nodes using Magneto 1.7. I would look at the hybrid environment that Rackspace offers.

Comment: wow 20 web nodes :) that's cool. Yeah i know that Magento is not bound to MySql but rather to php...now i see why you have 20 nodes. thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is more of a server configuration issue than a magento issue.